# Groovy groupby List generated from Map values

Tags: list, groovy

This is the List that I have

```
List a = ["Sep->Day02->FY21;Inter01","Sep->Day02->FY21;Inter02","Sep->Day02->FY21;Inter03","Sep->Day01->FY21;Inter18","Sep->Day01->FY21;Inter19"]
```

I am trying to group this and generate a new string

Expected result

```
"Sep->Day02->FY21",Inter01:Inter03
"Sep->Day01->FY21",Inter18:Inter19
```

Tried to do this

```
List a = ["Sep->Day02->FY21;Inter01","Sep->Day02->FY21;Inter02","Sep->Day02->FY21;Inter03","Sep->Day01->FY21;Inter18","Sep->Day01->FY21;Inter19"] 
List b = []
a.each{
b.add(it.split(";"))
}
def c = b.groupBy{it[0]}
println c
c.each{
 k, v -> println "${v}"
}
```

I cant find a way to get the range of Inter01:Inter03 in the string. Please advice.

**EDIT**

The solution provided by Marmite works in the groovy console as expected. The list I am generating is from values in a map.

```
a.add(map[z]) Where z is the key.
```

When I am trying to use it, it gives me max and min method not found errors.

Tried using map[z].toString(). Still the same. Is the fact that the values are from a map affecting the same?

**Code Snippet**
Below is how I generate the map

```
def map = [:]

itr.each{
def Per = it.getMemberName("Period") //getMemberName is a product specific function . Sample output May
def Day = it.getMemberName("Day") //Day01 sample output
def Hour = it.getMemberName("Hour") //Interval01 sample output
def HourInt = it.getMemberName("Hour").reverse().take(2).reverse()
def Year = it.getMemberName("Years")
map.put(it.DataAsDate.format("dd/MM/yyyy")+"-"+Hour,Year+"->"+Per+"->"+Day+";"+HourInt)
}
```

Below is where I generate the List

```
def OSTinterval = OST.reverse().take(2).reverse() as Integer //This creates 01 out of Interval01
def OETinterval = OET.reverse().take(2).reverse() as Integer //This creates 03 out of Interval03

D1 = new Date(OSDDay)
D2 = new Date(OEDDay)
if (D1 == D2)
{
(OSTinterval..OETinterval).each
{inter ->
z = OSDDay+"-"+"Interval"+inter.toString().padLeft(2,'0')
coll.add(map[z].toString())
}
}
else
{
(D1..D2).each { 
if (it == D1){
(OSTinterval..48).each
{inter ->
z = OSDDay+"-"+"Interval"+inter.toString().padLeft(2,'0')
coll.add(map[z].toString())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are looking for `min` and `max` after grouping.

I'm using a bit simplified data to focus on the processing:

```
def a = ['D02;I01','D02;I02','D02;I03','D01;I18','D01;I18']

println  a.collect{it.split(";")}
          .groupBy{it[0]}
          .collect{k,v -> [k,v.collect {it[1]}]}
          .collect{[it[0],"${it[1].min()}:${it[1].max()}"]}
          .collect{it.join(',')}
```

returns a list of the keys with the min and max of the values

```
[D02,I01:I03, D01,I18:I18]
```

result after `groupBy`

```
[D02:[[D02, I01], [D02, I02], [D02, I03]], D01:[[D01, I18], [D01, I18]]]
```

The next `collect` removes the duplicated keys

```
[[D02, [I01, I02, I03]], [D01, [I18, I18]]]
```

Finally you find the  `min` and `max` of the lists

```
[[D02, I01:I03], [D01, I18:I18]]
```

Comment: Hi Marmite, Thanks a ton for the help. I just updated the question. i am facing issues with using the max and min method. Would i need to convert the values before using it

Comment: @nshaw could you provide a simple snipped, how you get the data in `a`?

Comment: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#split(java.lang.String). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
@ line 122, column 22.
[Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Object#getAt(int). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.

Comment: Sorry to be confusing. What I asked for was someting like `def a = ['D02;I01','D02;I02','D02;I03','D01;I18','D01;I19']` where the the data is not a *list*, but a *map* and the expected output. It's not necessary to replay your application, *simple reproducible* example is enough.

Comment: This is the print of the map `{01/07/2020-Interval18=D01;18, 01/07/2020-Interval19=D01;19, 01/07/2020-Interval20=D01;20,10/07/2020-Interval47=D02;47, 10/07/2020-Interval48=D02;48, 10/07/2020-Interval01=D02;01}`After this, I am creating a string `z = OSDDay+"-"+"Interval"+inter.toString().padLeft(2,'0') `which will be equivalent to the first part and then I get the value using map[z] which is `D02;01` which I add to the list.

Comment: In the solution you provided how can I convert the second part to an integer. I tried .toInteger() etc. `collect{k,v -> [k,v.collect {it[1] as Integer}]}` I think the min and max are looking for integers and i am passing a string